# Is there a way to implement a zoomable UIPageViewController in iOS 5?

Tags: ios5, zooming

There is a new View Controller in iOS 5: UIPageViewController which supports to turn page like iBook. But there is a problem to support zoom in/out page.

Then I add a scrollview to RootViewController's view. And add UIPageViewController's view as a subview of this scrollview. Then the zoom in/out works in both portrait and landscape mode. But another problem arise. After I zoom in the view, the page turning gesture doesn't work anymore. I think this may because of the conflict between scrollview's gesture and pageview's gesture.

I noticed that there is a statement like this:

```
self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers;
```

So I change it to:

```
self.scrollView.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers;
```

But it crashes, the error message is something like:

*** -[UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6b80150

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Did you try putting the scroll view inside the page view controller's view, instead of the other way around?

Comment: I tried that. It's ok if you only have one Page View Controller in screen. But if you have two pages on the screen (spine location in the middle when in landscape mode), there will be problem.

Comment: To the original poster: It has been some days now, did you find out any useful answer?

Comment: No, this new UIPageViewController is useless for me although it's cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nonono, setting the gestureRecognizers to another array is really bad. It's just exposed so you can tweak them, but don't replace the whole array.

If you disable bouncing then the page turn works most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it backwards.

Put the scrollview(s) inside the pageviewcontroller and change the panning gesture on the scrollview to use more than one finger.